# OnMessageReceived event is called only once in GCM

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make simple sending notification from server app to mobile app.
My mobile app is implemented with Xamarin.Android and for server app I am using simple .NET Console App, just to pass notification to Google cloud Messaging.

This is my server app code:

```
class Program
{
    public const string API_KEY = "MYAPICODE";
    public const string MESSAGE = "Hello world!";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jGcmData = new JObject();
        var jData = new JObject();

        jData.Add("message", MESSAGE);
        jGcmData.Add("to", "/topics/global");
        jGcmData.Add("data", jData);

        var url = new Uri("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
                    "Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);

                Task.WaitAll(client.PostAsync(url,
                    new StringContent(jGcmData.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(0), "application/json"))
                    .ContinueWith(response =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(response);
                    }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to send GCM message:");
        }

    }
}
```

And on client side I have this in Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="za.co.beemobile.mylegislature" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <user-premission android:name="za.co.beemobile.mylegislature.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission android:name="za.co.beemobile.mylegislature.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <application android:label="My Legislature" android:icon="@drawable/my_parliament">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION"/> 
                <category android:name="za.co.beemobile.mylegislature" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And this is code that I use on client:

```
[Service(Exported = false)]
class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
{
    static object locker = new object();
    private const string SENDER_ID = "MYSENDERID";
    public RegistrationIntentService() : base("RegistrationIntentService") { }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken");
            lock (locker)
            {
                var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance(this);
                var token = instanceID.GetToken(
                    SENDER_ID, GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

                Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
                SendRegistrationToAppServer(token);
                Subscribe(token);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug("RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to get a registration token");
            return;
        }
    }

    void SendRegistrationToAppServer(string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation here as needed.
    }

    void Subscribe(string token)
    {
        var pubSub = GcmPubSub.GetInstance(this);
        pubSub.Subscribe(token, "/topics/global", null);
    }
}
```

This is code from `MyLegislatureInstanceIDListenerService.cs` class:

```
[Service(Exported = true), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" })]
public class MyLegislatureInstanceIDListenerService : InstanceIDListenerService
{
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(RegistrationIntentService));
        StartService(intent);
    }
}
```

And this is where code for event is:

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
public class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
    {
        var message = data.GetString("message");
        SendNotification(message);
    }

    void SendNotification(string message)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.clock)
            .SetContentTitle("BEE")
            .SetContentText(message)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

What happened is that when I've run code for the first time, break points on message receive event were hit and my notification sent from server app was shown on android emulator.
Every single next try to send same notification to same emulator didn't work. Break points inside event were never hit, even though message is sent from server to GCM. 
Did someone had this problem? What am I doing wrongly? I want to be able to send this notification more than once of course.

Note: Message wasn't send even when I run new instances of android and server apps.

Comment: Suggest you to use FCM.

Comment: try this link hope its helpful https://github.com/Praveent696/FCMSharp